# case_when setup in R - example code gives errors

Tags: r, dplyr

I am copying some example code from this page: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_match.html

i am having trouble getting case_when to work.  my code is:

```
library(dplyr)
# `case_when()` is not a tidy eval function. If you'd like to reuse
# the same patterns, extract the `case_when()` call in a normal
# function:
case_character_type <- function(height, mass, species) {
  case_when(
    height > 200 | mass > 200 ~ "large",
    species == "Droid" ~ "robot",
    .default = "other"
  )
}

case_character_type(150, 250, "Droid")
#> [1] "large"
```

the output i get is:

```
Error in case_when( (scratch_31.R#6): Case 3 (`height > 200 | mass > 200 ~ "large"`) must be a two-sided formula, not a character vector.
```

i am not parsing in any character vectors, and the code is literally copied from the example page documentation.

What am i doing wrongly?

```
version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin20.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin20.6.0        
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          2.2                         
year           2022                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        83211                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
nickname       Innocent and Trusting       

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.7.4

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.0.10
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `.default = ` parameter in `case_when` was introduced in `dplyr` version 1.1.0 (you have version 1.0.10). The syntax for older version should be `TRUE ~ "other"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error in your call to `case_when()` appears to be the reference to `.default`.  If you want a blanket catch all case, use `TRUE` as the condition:

```r
case_character_type <- function(height, mass, species) {
    case_when(
        height > 200 | mass > 200 ~ "large",
        species == "Droid" ~ "robot",
        TRUE ~ "other"
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and the documentation didn't bother to do that?
errors like that really make learning a new language harder than it needs to be.

Comment: R's documentation admittedly is not the most user friendly or best.  This is why you need to rely on sites like this, to show you how to actually use an API correctly.